# Many broadcast data frame over my Wi-Fi channel

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-access-point, wireshark

I occasionally experience unstable connection to the Wi-Fi AP I use, so I used wireshark to sniff the packets on the same channel of my Wi-Fi network using monitor mode. I surprisingly find a lot of broadcast data packets, like these:

[Screenshot of the broadcast data packets on Wireshark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QP60i.png)

I am not sure if this is the cause of the unstable connection, but it sounds weird to see so many such packets.

The blackened source addresses in the screenshot are all the same, and it is not the MAC address of my router or any of my devices. This device is only sending packets (some are not broadcast, but most are); no packet destinates to this MAC address. The device seems to be a Wi-Fi AP because I can see its beacon frames:

[Screenshot of the beacon frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwH0x.png)

However, this network is not shown when I do `iwlist <interface> scan`. Instead, I find another network on another channel with a similar MAC address and with a SSID called "mesh", so the AP above may be a mesh AP?

I am wondering why are there so many broadcast data packets? Is that normal? Would that lead to unstable/slow Wi-Fi connection if my network is on the same channel as these broadcast packets?

Unfortunately I have no control over the Wi-Fi AP I use, because it is a free public Wi-Fi provided by the building and the maintenance does not know how to maintain a Wi-Fi, so I cannot switch it to another channel. Any suggestion to avoid unstable connection if these packets are indeed the trouble?

Thank you!

Comment: What is the BSSID of the packets in question? Is that BSSID one of yours? What data rate (PHY rate) are these broadcasts being sent at?

Comment: @Spiff The BSSID is not one of mine. How can I measure the data rate of these packets?

Comment: @Spiff If I just calculate the data rate based on the packets in the screenshot, it is around 97 Kbps. This is not a large number, but not sure if that can cause troubles.

Comment: The PHY rate should be in the radiotap headers (or other radio metadata headers) of the packets you captured. But if you already multiplied the number of these you get per second by the average size, and came up with 97kbps then you already know this is only a tiny tiny trickle of data that probably isn't eating up much airtime even if it were being sent at the lowest PHY rate. Nothing to worry about.

Comment: @Spiff In the radiotap headers, it says "Data rate: 6.0 Mb/s". Is that the PHY rate you are referring to? If it is it, it seems large because when I do speedtest I get only 20 Mbps. 6 Mbps is 30% of that.

Comment: Yes, that's the PHY rate. It's the signaling speed that was used for that particular packet. So if it's a 220 byte packet like most in your screenshot, that's 220 * 8 = 1760 bits, then divide that by 6,000,000 bps, and you learn it took only 293 microseconds to transmit, which means it would take 34 of those packets per second to even reach 1% of your airtime. So your 97kbps of broadcast traffic is only taking up around 1.5% of the airtime on that channel.